# Why I am seeing an email address offending my name?

Tags: gmail

When I succeed the username recovery process, I saw a suspicious address i didn't know of. How was this added to my list of known accounts? (see below)

[image]

Comment: Are you the only one using this computer ?

Comment: I found that it was not my list of known accounts but it's a step of Google's verification process, you have to choose an email address you recognize and then confirm the code. But it seems a light-headed entity created another email-address with the same surname + firstname.

Comment: By this i'm gonna silently delete the question

Comment: Does this mean th eowner of the spurous mailaddress can get hold of your account (e.g., via password recovery)?